# SvelteKit authentication issues with persistency

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-store

Issue Description:

- I'm building a web application using Svelte and Node.js.
- The application has user authentication using JWT tokens, and you store these tokens and user information in cookies.
- The authentication status is not persisting between page refreshes. Even though you're seeing the tokens and user data in your console, the UI doesn't reflect the correct login/logout state.

---

Although I'm getting authToken, refreshToken cookies and userId each time I refresh my webpage, it's not being persistent

1. Not logged In - I supposed to see Login/Registration
2. Logged in - I supposed to see Logoug/Profile

When trying to logging in, I get to see Logout button, but on refresh it's gone (showing login/register again) although my console.log is showing that cookies and user data on page refresh are present

I tried to write stores to differentiate, but it's not helping. I'm connected to NodeJS server by the way. My Postman(backend) works like a charm, but frontend doesn't work well.

---

stores.ts

```
     import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
    
 export const UserId = writable(null);

export const setUserId = (id) => {
    UserId.set(id);
    return UserId;
};

// ---------------------------------------------

export const Authenticated = writable(false);

// Function to update the Authenticated store
export const setUserAuthenticated = (auth) => {
    Authenticated.set(auth);
    return Authenticated;
};
```

Navbar.svelte

```
     {#if $Authenticated}
                <div class="button-container">
                    <Button
                            element="a"
                            href="/profile"
                            variant="outline"
                            color="green">Profile
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-container" on:click={handleSubmit}>
                    <Button
                            element="a"
                            href="/"
                            variant="outline"
                            color="red">Logout
                    </Button>
                </div>
            {:else }
                <div class="button-container">
                    <Button
                            element="a"
                            href="/login"
                            variant="outline"
                            color="green">Login
                    </Button>
                </div>
                <div class="button-container">
                    <Button
                            element="a"
                            href="/register"
                            variant="outline"
                            color="red">Registration
                    </Button>
                </div>
            {/if}
```

+layout.server.ts

```
import type { LayoutServerLoad } from './$types';
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import {setUserAuthenticated, UserId} from "$helpers/stores";

export const load: LayoutServerLoad = async ({ cookies }) => {
    const authToken = cookies.get('auth-token');
    const refreshToken = cookies.get('refresh-token');

    console.log('Auth token in LAYOUT.SERVER::::::::: ', authToken);
    console.log('Refresh token in LAYOUT.SERVER::::::::: ', refreshToken);

    function handleAuthentication(authToken) {
        let userId = null;

        UserId.subscribe((uid) => {
            userId = uid;
        });

        if (!authToken) {
            console.log('No authToken present');
            setUserAuthenticated(false);
            return {
                user: null,
            };
        }

        try {
            const secretKey = 'farmTokenSecrets';
            const decodedAuthToken = jwt.verify(authToken, secretKey);
            userId = decodedAuthToken.userId ?? userId;
            setUserAuthenticated(true); // Update the Authenticated store
            console.log('User ID in LAYOUT.SERVER::::::::: ', userId);
            return {
                user: {
                    userId: userId,
                },
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error decoding auth-token:', error);
            setUserAuthenticated(false);
            return {
                user: null,
            };
        }
    }


    return handleAuthentication(authToken);
};
```

[Output on page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm7Tm.png)

Comment: As far as I know, using stores inside load functions is not a good idea and you should avoid it. Regardless, since you are returning the userId should work. Did you try console logging it in the svelte component? Does it show up? Maybe you could do your if/else logic depending on whether the userId exists or not.

Comment: {#if $Authenticated}
    <p>You ARE authenticated</p>
{:else}
    <p>You are NOT authenticated</p>
{/if}
{console.log($Authenticated)}
{@debug $Authenticated}

So by testing these, on the first try I get true, but on page refresh, it's false

Comment: Try using `debug` or console logging the write function for the `Authenticated` store. My guess is that it's only being written on the server side and not translated to the client side. A cursory google search for "how to set a svelte store from load function" revealed that it shouldn't really be done, and to try to use `onMount` instead.

If you use `userId` for the if/else instead of `Authenticated` does it work?

Comment: You should use SvelteKit's hooks to store user, like explained in this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaF8kRbHbi0&t=3960s) video.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around in the docs a bit, I believe [this chapter in the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/state-management#using-stores-with-context) should be exactly what you need. I mentioned in the comments that you shouldn't use stores in the load but I didn't mention what's the alternative (because I didn't know it for sure myself), but using the svelte context in combination with stores should be what you are looking for.